# How to join two or more tables in entity framework and display selected columns from each tables in data grid view

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have generated Entity from database using `VS`. Now  when I want to join two tables from my database and show the result using datagrid view.

my LINQ is :

```
 result = (from lang in my_entity.LANGUAGE
                              join c in my_entity.COUNTRY
                              on lang.COUNTRY_ID equals c.ID
                              select lang).ToList<LANGUAGE>();

dgvresult.DataSource  =  result;
dgvresult.Refresh();
```

All the columns from Language tables are shown but none are shown from Country table. 
I want few columns from language and few columns from country table to be shown in datagrid view.

How do I do it. Any learning links are also appreciated. 
Also I want to learn DataGrid View in detail. If any one can suggest good books or materials , please do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new anonymous type and then bind to it, like so:

```
 result = (from lang in my_entity.LANGUAGE
                              join c in my_entity.COUNTRY
                              on lang.COUNTRY_ID equals c.ID
                              select new 
                              { 
                                   lang.Col1,
                                   land.col2,
                                   c.Col1,
                                   c.Col2
                              }).ToList();

dgvresult.DataSource  =  result;
dgvresult.Refresh();
```

Or you can create a view model and simply select the values into it:

```
public class LangCountryModel 
{
    public string LangCol1 { get; set; }
    public string LangCol2 { get; set; }
    public string CountryCol1 { get; set; }
    public string CountryCol2 { get; set; }
}

     result = (from lang in my_entity.LANGUAGE
                                  join c in my_entity.COUNTRY
                                  on lang.COUNTRY_ID equals c.ID
                                  select new LangCountryModel 
                                  { 
                                       LangCol1 = lang.Col1,
                                       LangCol2 = land.col2,
                                       CountryCol1 = c.Col1,
                                       CountryCol2 = c.Col2
                                  }).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 Because of the view model suggestion. Often a better solution in the long run.

Comment: if I enclose your anonymous query into function then what will be the return type of the function ?

Comment: You could return it as a System.Object (I think..) but you really shouldn't as its massively hacky.  If you want to wrap the call up in a Method I'd recommend going down the strongly typed View Model route.  The return type would then be IEnumerable<LangCountryModel>.

Comment: You can also do it without using the `Join` LINQ keyword by using the navigation property `COUNTRY` of the source table `LANGUAGE` like this:
`result = (from lang in my_entity.LANGUAGE
                          select new 
                              { 
                                   lang.Col1,
                                   lang.col2,
                                   lang.COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID 
                              }).ToList();

dgvresult.DataSource  =  result;
dgvresult.Refresh();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = (from ob1 in lista1   
              join ob2 in lista2    
              on ob1.Id equals ob2.Id  
              select new   
                   {  
                        ob1.Age,  
                        ob2.CarName  
                   }).ToList();

dgvresult.DataSource  =  result;  
dgvresult.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @pingoo answer with a small edit:

You can do it without using the `Join` LINQ keyword by using the navigation property `COUNTRY` of the source table `LANGUAGE` like this:

```
result = (from lang in my_entity.LANGUAGE
                select new {
                          lang.Col1,
                          lang.col2,
                          lang.COUNTRY.COUNTRY_ID
                          }).ToList();
dgvresult.DataSource = result; dgvresult.Refresh();`
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(...).ToList<LANGUAGE>()
.Select(p=>new{p.LanguageProp,p.COUNTRY.COUNTRYProp,...})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Can you please explain it. I am getting errors . My function signature is: public IList<LANGUAGE> GetLanguage(FILTER filter, String param) { }
I am getting errors if I use your solution. Can you please explain a little bit ?